# Android :use sendgrid to send email

Tags: android, android-studio, sendgrid

I'm trying to integrate send grid with android I can't figure out how to do it since there is no sdk for android any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I've created and maintain an Android library for Sendgrid targetting their latest API, 3. It's available through JitPack:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {
     implementation 'com.github.Jakebreen:android-sendgrid:1.2.2'
}
```

https://github.com/Jakebreen/android-sendgrid

If you have any questsions or feature requests you can open an issue on the Github repo's issue tracker.

Comment: that's great..Is it possible to use it with custom template with sendgrid since it's required to use it

Comment: You can set the ID of the template ```setTemplateId(String id)```, each ```SendGridMail``` can have only one template.

Comment: thank you it great work ..but I'm not able to figure out how can I pass data to my template throw library @JakeB

Comment: Are you refering to dyanmic templates that use the ```dynamic_template_data``` field? https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates/#send-a-transactional-email

I can add this to the library if so

Comment: yeah..I desgin templete and I want it to be more customize by pass data like name ,date

Comment: I've created a pre-release beta with a new method to set a JSONObject of key/value pairs: ```mail.setDynamicTemplateData(@NonNull JSONObject jsonObject)```. Please let me know if it's working as you would expect... ```implementation 'com.github.Jakebreen:android-sendgrid:1.2.0-beta.1'```. Updated readme here: https://github.com/Jakebreen/android-sendgrid/tree/feature/dynamic-template-data